# Let $V$ be an inner product space over $\mathbb{C}$, prove the Polar Identities: For $x,y\in V$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $\langle x,y\rangle=\displaystyle\frac{1}{4}\sum\limits_{k=1}^4 i^k\lVert x+i^ky\rVert^2 $ where $F=\mathbb C$ and $i^2=-1$.

**Proof:** We have
$$
\begin{align}
  \lVert x+i^ky\rVert^2 
  &= \langle x+i^ky,x+i^ky\rangle \\
  &= \langle x,x\rangle + \langle i^ky,x\rangle + \langle x,i^ky\rangle + \langle i^ky,i^ky\rangle \\
  &= \langle x,x\rangle + \overline{\langle x,i^ky\rangle} + \langle x,i^ky\rangle + \langle i^ky,i^ky\rangle \\
  &= \langle x,x\rangle + 2Re \langle x,i^ky\rangle + \langle i^ky,i^ky\rangle \\
  &= \lVert x\rVert^2 + 2Re \langle x,i^ky\rangle + \langle i^ky,i^ky\rangle \\
  &= \lVert x\rVert^2 + 2Re[\overline{ i^k}\langle x,y\rangle] + \lVert i^ky\rVert^2
\end{align}
$$

From here I'm not getting how to move on. Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^4i^k\Vert x+i^ky\Vert^2
&=\frac{1}{4}\left(i\Vert x+iy\Vert^2-\Vert x-y\Vert^2
-i\Vert x-iy\Vert^2+\Vert x+y\Vert^2\right)\\
&=\frac{i}{4}\left(\Vert x+iy\Vert^2-\Vert x-iy\Vert^2\right)
+\frac{1}{4}\left(\Vert x+y\Vert^2-\Vert x-y\Vert^2\right)\\
&=\frac{i}{4}\cdot2\left(\langle x,iy\rangle+\langle iy,x\rangle\right)
+\frac{1}{4}\cdot2\left(\langle x,y\rangle+\langle y,x\rangle\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}\cdot2\left(-\langle x,y\rangle+\langle y,x\rangle\right)
+\frac{1}{4}\cdot4\cdot{\rm Re}\langle x,y\rangle\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}\cdot2\left(-2\cdot{\rm Im}\langle x,y\rangle\right)
+{\rm Re}\langle x,y\rangle\\
&={\rm Im}\langle x,y\rangle+{\rm Re}\langle x,y\rangle\\
&=\langle x,y\rangle.
\end{align}